# Get a part of string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string as

```
"cmp197_10_27_147ee7b825-2a3b-4520-b36c-bba08f8b0d87_TempDoc_197"
```

I want to fetch the last digits(i.e. 197)
For obtaining same i have implemented below code

```
int lastUnderscore = addUcoid.LastIndexOf('_');
string getucoid = addUcoid.Substring(lastUnderscore).TrimStart('_');
```

The `getucoid` string gets the digit part properly.The problem now is that I have to also check if the digits occur in string,i.e. string can be like

```
"cmp197_10_27_147ee7b825-2a3b-4520-b36c-bba08f8b0d87_TempDoc"
```

How to perform the check on such string, whether that part(197) exists at the end in the string or not.

Here 197 is just an example.It could be any numeric data,for example 196,145,etc

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to retrieve the _last occurrence_ of numbers in any given string?

Comment: tip: `string getucoid = addUcoid.Substring(lastUnderscore + 1);` (as long as you check whether `lastUnderscore` is non-negative first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just want to know if this last part is a numeric or not:

```
bool isNumeric = Regex.IsMatch(getucoid, @"^\d+$");
```

Answer (score 2):

`string.Contains` won't help: we know it is there at least once already. I would use:

```
int otherLocation = addUcoid.IndexOf(getucoid);
```

and compare this to `lastUnderscore`. If `otherLocation` is non-negative and less than `lastUnderscore`, then it is there in an earlier position too. You could also use:

```
int otherLocation = addUcoid.IndexOf(getucoid, 0, lastUnderscore);
```

and compare to `-1`; this second approach stops at the underscore, so won't find the instance from the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think Regex is the easiest way. If `match.Success` is true the digits have been found.

```
Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(addUcoid, @"(?<=_)\d+$");
if(match.Success)
{
    int i = int.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say exists at the "end in the string", do you mean if it exists anywhere in the string? You can do a .Contains() to get it.

```
bool inTheString = addUcoid.Contains(getucoid);
```

Also:

FYI, your code:

```
int lastUnderscore = addUcoid.LastIndexOf('_');
string getucoid = addUcoid.Substring(lastUnderscore).TrimStart('_');
```

can be <del>simplified</del> shortened into:

```
string getucoid = addUcoid.Split('_').Last();
```

EDIT:

Ehm, Marc Gravell rightly points out that the string is there anyway. If you want to find out if another instance of the string is there (aside from getucoid):

```
int lastUnderscore = addUcoid.LastIndexOf('_');
string getucoid = addUcoid.Split('_').Last();
bool inTheString = addUcoid.Substring(0,lastUnderscore).Contains(getucoid);
```

Comment: "can be simplified into:" ... the code as shown in the question is more efficient, though. I'd just do a `string getucoid = addUcoid.Substring(lastUnderscore + 1);`

Comment: Interesting! Searched for comparisons on Split and Indexof but I couldn't find any though.

Comment: you can deduce this yourself; which is more expensive: creating a single sub-string from a single start / length pair computed once, ... or creating an *array* containing *every* component substring, after detecting, in a loop, the start/length pairs of all instances of a given token...?

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.EndsWith` method to findout.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 string s="cmp197_10_27_147ee7b825-2a3b-4520-b36c-bba08f8b0d87_TempDoc";
    bool isends=s.EndsWith("197");//returns false;
    s="cmp197_10_27_147ee7b825-2a3b-4520-b36c-bba08f8b0d87_TempDoc_197";
    isends=s.EndsWith("197");//returns true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The presence of a substring can be checked with `String.Contains()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Assuming you have removed the final "_197" after checking that it exists, calling `Contains("197")` on your string will return true if `"197"` is a substring, or false if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ (also to check if the last char is a digit):

```
string str = "cmp197_10_27_147ee7b825-2a3b-4520-b36c-bba08f8b0d87_TempDoc_197";

if (Char.IsDigit(str.Last()))
{
    string digits = new string(str.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).Reverse().ToArray());
}
```